# How do I input the results of a query run in a MySql database, and upload the results in a different table in the same database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have looked at the suggestions of similar questions, and nothing worked for me, or was the same issue I am having.

I am running this query in MySql database. I need, either a way to convert the query to run on a classic ASP page, or a way to insert the results into another table.

The query is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TAGS_,',',mCtr),',',-1) AS
 valsAsRows FROM (SELECT (cb.ctr*cc.ctr)+ca.ctr AS mCtr FROM (SELECT 1 ctr 
UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) ca CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 ctr 
UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) cb CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT 0 ctr UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4)
 cc GROUP BY mCtr) mc CROSS JOIN STORIES GROUP BY valsAsRows;
```

I want to upload the results into a table called STORY_TAGS in a field called TAG_

Or convert the query into something I can work with in classic asp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, if the table STORY_TAGS  has only 1 column, if you have mire you need to add them to your select query or name the column you have

```
INSERT INTO STORY_TAGS (mytagvalue)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TAGS_,',',mCtr),',',-1) AS
 valsAsRows FROM (SELECT (cb.ctr*cc.ctr)+ca.ctr AS mCtr FROM (SELECT 1 ctr 
UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) ca CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 ctr 
UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) cb CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT 0 ctr UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4)
 cc GROUP BY mCtr) mc CROSS JOIN STORIES GROUP BY valsAsRows;
```

Comment: Now let's change it up a bit. If I want to take the items in the field called TAGS_ in a table named TEMP_TAGS, do the same parsing as above, but insert them into the field TAGS_ in the table STORY_TAGS, what would I change in the above query??
I am not sure what to change in order to have it query one table, but have it insert into another table.

Comment: that is a new question, so make a new one still you need to provide more details, for example wfy has STORY_TAGS and TEMP_TAGS the same structure? but basically you need to runb the query new with the seond table or you write a trigger that autmatucally inserts in the second table